# How to have an applet trasmit an image to web server

Tags: java, applet

I am working on an applet which interfaces with a signature pad and can write the image to a file with this code:

```
sigObj.setImageXSize(30);
sigObj.setImageYSize(10);
sigObj.setImageJustifyMode(5);
sigObj.setImagePenWidth(5);
BufferedImage sigImage = sigObj.sigImage();
try
{
int w = sigImage.getWidth(null);
int h = sigImage.getHeight(null);
int[] pixels = new int[(w * h) * 2];

sigImage.setRGB(0, 0, 0, 0, pixels, 0, 0);
FileOutputStream fos = new
FileOutputStream("c:\\_img\\sig.jpg");
JPEGImageEncoder jpeg = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(fos);
jpeg.encode(sigImage);
fos.close();                            
}
catch (java.io.IOException exception) { System.out.println("Error IO Exception."); }
```

The goal is to transmitted the file to the web server and ultimately put the .jpg or .bmp image in to an Oracle blob.  What’s the best way to do this?

Just guessing here:

Method 1:
Have the applet write the .jpg file as a hex encoded string, move the string to a hidden form field and then submit the page where oracle can read the hidden field and convert it to a blob in pl/sql with    `blobVar := HEXTORAW( url('sigJpg'));`

Method 2: 
Have the applet do a POST and submit the file

My java skills are pretty green, so I’m not 100% sure if either of these methods are recommended.  Once the file is moved to the web server, I’m pretty sure I can find a way to stuff it into the db using Oracle pl/sql.  I’m not sure how to get the file to the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.   I found a post from 2004 where someone was doing the same thing.  The only difference is I’m turning the file into a hex string before the posting.   The only reason I’m doing this is because I know how to turn the hex string into a blob in Oracle.

```
private String byteToString(byte[] data) {

    String text = new String();

    for ( int i = 0; i < data.length; i++ )
        text += (char) ( data[i] & 0x00FF );
    return text;
}

private static String bytesToHexString(byte[] bytes) {   
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);   

    Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb);   
    for (byte b : bytes) {   
        formatter.format("%02x", b);   
    }   

    return sb.toString();   
}  


public void writeImageToServer(URL scriptURL, BufferedImage img){
 try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream jpegOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(jpegOutput);

        encoder.encode(img); // imagedata are coded here

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)
        scriptURL.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        byte[] imageData = jpegOutput.toByteArray();

        //String imageString = byteToString(imageData);     // if you want a string
        String imageString = bytesToHexString(imageData);   // if you want hex string
        String content = "img=" + URLEncoder.encode (imageString,"UTF-8");

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(content.length()));

        OutputStream urlout = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

        DataOutputStream printOut = new DataOutputStream(urlout);
        printOut.writeBytes(content); // writing data to the serverscript

        urlout.flush();
        urlout.close();
        printOut.flush();
        printOut.close();
        jpegOutput.flush();
        jpegOutput.close();

        urlConnection.disconnect();

        //System.err.println("Serverresponse: "+ urlConnection.getResponseMessage());

        // this works in firefox
        //try { getAppletContext().showDocument (new URL("javascript:msg(\""+ urlConnection.getResponseMessage() + "\")")); } catch (MalformedURLException me) { }

    }
    catch( IOException e ){ e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

In oracle via mod_plsql:

```
procedure image_post_handeler ( img varchar2) is 
    b blob;
begin
    b := HEXTORAW( UTL_URL.UNESCAPE(url('img')) );
    insert into image_table (id,  b) values (id_seq.nextval, b  );  
end;
```

To be production ready, it will have to be able to make an https connection and possibly cookies.  I could get around the cookie issue if I pass a url parameter.

I may decide to hand the hex string back to the browser, put it in a hidden field within a form an then submit the form.

There may be better ways of doing this.  It’s been a heck of a ride learning how to create an applet, jar the class, sign it, put .dll files all over the place.  Just figuring out what java home the applets runs in was a challenge there about 6, some 32 bit and some 64 bit.

Thanks for the help.  It gave me a better idea of what I needed to google.  Comments very much appreciated.

Comment: After working with this for a bit, I found a few things:    1. The httpurlconnection can handle https connections.  2. Adding additional url parameters is the same as making a get url, so the connection string can be written like this: "f=1234&img=" + imageString  3. There is no need to encode the hex string or decode it at the db. The hex string will contain no special characters.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  Make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that other may learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

Your method 2 is the method you should implement. Actually it is not a so huge problem. Here is a good example for you: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Post.html

You should write your image to stream you get from URL connection exactly as you do when you are writing it to file.

But this is not enough. You have to implement the server side. Typically you should implement servlet and override its `doPost()` method where you will get the content of your post. Then do what you need: open JDBC connection and write file to DB. Although I do not recommend this approach: you have nothing to do with BLOBs in DB. I think that better way is to write image to file system and store only path to it in DB.

I hope I gave you enough tips. You can find more details by 2 minutes googleing. Good luck.

Comment: Using the example, the image is written to the URL connection (and never touches the local filesystem). Wow, this would be nice.  I do not want to use JDBC.  The webpage that the applet is setting in has session/cookie info.  Really it would be nice if this is also transmitted with the http POST (if it's not already).<br> Also storing the image as blob makes it easy to restrict who can see it, without the need for .access files.